# Why the internal compiler of Ethereum Remix Vscode extention doesn’t work?

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity

I installed ethereum remix vscode extension and tried to compile a .sol file.

To be specific, I did following 1-3.

1. open a .sol file I want to compile .
2. click remix logo in activity bar and load remix extension.
3. click the compiler logo on the side bar and click the suggested file name which is equal to the opened file name.

If the compiler was working correctly, I could see compile logs in the output tab.
(Is that right?)
But no logs were printed in the output tab.

On the other hand, when I activated run and deploy ,logs were correctly printed in the output tab. So I thought that the compiler didn’t work for some reason.

Questions are :

- Why the compiler doesn’t work?
- How to make the compiler work?

Comment: I have the same issue right now. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead.
look at your first folder opened or a workspace

Comment: maybe you have too much folder opened

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).